# How can I have numbering for chapters only?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I would like to have the chapters only with numbers, but not inferior divisions like sections and subsections (using the book document class in LaTeX). All divisions should be present in the TOC. I don't care if parts are numbered since I don't use them. Is there a simple and convenient way to get this result?

Comment: short answer: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`, and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`, but i'm sure this has been asked/answered before.

Comment: I haven't found the exact same question, however I had tried this based on a related answer -- but it didn't work. After your answer and Andrew's, I started creating a MWE to show it didn't work on my side, and realized that I was importing a style file that interfered with this. So, it helped to be sure about the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the counter `secnumdepth`.  Making this `0` means chapters are numbered but not sections, `1` numbers sections but not subsections.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test section}

\subsection{Test subsection}

\chapter{More}

\end{document}
```